# Auto adjust divs height to fill up the remaining space

Tags: css

I have 2 `div`s. I gave the first one a `height` of `70px` and now I want the 2<sup>nd</sup> `div` to fill up the remaining space of the webpage. This should be relative to the first div. Below is my code: (The 2 `div`s are `header` and `content`)

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#header {
  background-color: #1874CD;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}

#name {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

#content {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing something like this
([JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/nQCEp/)):

```
#header{
    background-color: #1874CD;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}


#content{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    padding-top: 70px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;   
}
```

Comment: since padding might be needed inside the box, i prefer another solution: top: 70px; bottom: 0px; and you can leave height out.